# Can't seem to fix my 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm unsure if the problem in my program is simply in where I declared the arrays, or if I'm stuffing one of them with more than they can take.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class EliminateDuplicates {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numberList = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Please enter ten integers.");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {

        numberList[i] = input.nextInt();

        }

    int[] newNumberList = new int[10];

    newNumberList = eliminateDuplicates(numberList);


    System.out.println("The discrete numbers are: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < newNumberList.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(newNumberList[i] + ' ');

        }

    }

public static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] numberList) {

    int[] noDuplicateList = new int[numberList.length];

    int size = 0;

    java.util.Arrays.sort(numberList);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {

        if (numberList[i] != numberList[i+1]) {

            noDuplicateList[i] = numberList[i];

            size++;
        }

    }

    return noDuplicateList;
}
```

}

This is the output + the error message I get:

```
Please enter ten integers.
9
8
7
3
3
4
1
2
8
6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at EliminateDuplicates.eliminateDuplicates(EliminateDuplicates.java:51)
at EliminateDuplicates.main(EliminateDuplicates.java:28)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length - 1; i++) {
     if (numberList[i] != numberList[i+1]) {
```

When `i` reaches `numberList.length-1`, `i+1` is out of the array bounds.

You should change the range of the loop. You shold also use the `size` index when assigning to the `noDuplicateList` list, otherwise you will have gaps in that list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length - 1; i++) {
    if (numberList[i] != numberList[i+1]) {
        noDuplicateList[size] = numberList[i];
        size++;
    }
}
```

You would still have a minor problem. Since your `eliminateDuplicates` methods returns an array of the same size as the input, if there were duplicates, the output array would have unused indices in its end (that will contain zeroes). If you wish to avoid that, you can add all the items of the input array to a `HashSet`, find the `size()` of that set, and create an array of that size for the output. Using a `Set` will also simplify your code, since the `Set` would eliminate the duplicates for you, and you don't have to sort the input array.

```
public static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] numberList) {

    Set<Integer> noDups = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int num : numberList)  
        noDups.add(num);

    int[] noDuplicateList = new int[noDups.size()];

    Iterator<Integer> iter = noDups.iterator();
    for (int i=0; i<noDuplicateList.length && iter.hasNext();i++)
         noDuplicateList[i]=iter.next();

    return noDuplicateList;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was sort of wondering if there was a better way to do that...Still have weird 30s numbers though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here, `eliminateDuplicates`:

```
if (numberList[i] != numberList[i+1]) {// i+1, for the last elements raise the exception
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (numberList[i] != numberList[i+1])
```

when `i=9` this would look for index `10` which is out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this line:

```
if (numberList[i] != numberList[i+1]) {
```

If i is equals `numberList.length` the second condition is out of bounds.

So you have to change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
```

TO:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length-1; i++) {
```